# How to install Chromedriver for Arch Linux for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I understand `Chromedriver` by default is not added to the path or even not even present in system. I am leaning `selenium` from scratch using documentation it shows how to install `selenium` and a basic script to perform `get` action using `selenium`. My system shows different errors it is really hard to cope up with it I already have `Chromium` browser installed on my system and from errors and some research online I can see that I may not have `Chromedriver` installed and configured in the path. Even if I do install it, maybe I need to specify the path to the `Driver` object in the `python` script to the location of the `Chromedriver` is there any other alternative to it, why in the documentation they have not mentioned it already, it is really confusing as where to start from.

Here is the error I am getting upon executing the script

```
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Can any body guide me to install `Chromediver` and set it up so that I can run my `python` script.

Answer (score 1):

As of `selenium 4.10.0` there is no need to install Chromedriver.
Example from [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#example-explained):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Simplified example for Chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: Thanks @Bibhav for your kind help, my mistake I was reading docs from `https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/` there it is not mentioned that I do not need to install `Chromedriver` separately. It still gives me error when I use `webdriver.Chrome`, for `webdriver.Firefox` works just fine.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you trying to run a ChromeDriver instance for a profile in use?

Answer (score 0):

**Unless you are using latest selenium versions like 4.10.0**

Visit the Chromedriver download page: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads and download the appropriate version of Chromedriver for your operating system (Windows, macOS, Linux).

Now in your Python script, before creating a webdriver.Chrome instance, specify the path to Chromedriver using the executable_path parameter. For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_path = '/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
```